# Android Room Foreign Key onDelte = Cascade has no effect

Tags: java, android, foreign-keys, android-room, cascade

I have a one-to-many relationship between two tables. The parent table is "People", the child table is "Pets". A person can have many pets. A pet can have only one Person.

I create the relation between the two tables in PersonWithPets.java using @Relation. In Pets.java, I am using ForeignKey with onDelete = CASCADE. But if I delete a Person, the corresponding Pets remain in the database, and I can't figure out why. I almost seems as if onDelte = CASCADE has no effect.
Maybe I am not using the right id's, but I have been over this many times and just can't seem to figure out why the pets of a person are not deleted with the person.

Of course I could use the personId of the pets to iterate and delete all Pets sharing the same personId, but that just seems like defying the purpose of the @ForeignKey annotation.

What could I be missing?
Sorry, if this is obvious. I am new to Android.

**Person.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "person")
public class Person {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Integer id;

    String name;

    @Ignore
    private List<Pet> pets = null;

    public Person(){
        // empty constructor for serialization
    }

    @Ignore
    public Person(String name, List<Pet> pets) {
        this.name = name;
        this.pets = pets;
    }

    public Person(PersonWithPets personWithPets) {
        this.id = personWithPets.getPerson().getId();
        this.name = personWithPets.getPerson().getName();
        this.pets = this.getPets(personWithPets);
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setPet(Pet pet) {
        if (this.pets == null) {
            this.pets = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        this.pets.add(pet);
    }

    public List<Pet> getPets() {
        return this.pets;
    }

    private List<Pet> getPets(PersonWithPets personWithPets) {
        return personWithPets.getPets();
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**Pet.java**

```
@Entity(tableName = "pet")
public class Pet {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Integer id;

    String name;

    public Pet() {
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     */
    @Ignore
    public Pet(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @ForeignKey
            (entity = Person.class,
                    parentColumns = "id",
                    childColumns = "personId",
                    onDelete = CASCADE,
                    onUpdate = CASCADE)
    private Integer personId;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Integer getPersonId() {
        return personId;
    }

    public void setPersonId(Integer personId) {
        this.personId = personId;
    }
}
```

**PersonWithPets.java**

```
public class PersonWithPets {
    @Embedded public Person person;

    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "id",
            entityColumn = "personId",
            entity = Pet.class
    )
    public List<Pet> pets;

    public Person getPerson() {
        return person;
    }

    public List<Pet> getPets() {
        return pets;
    }
}
```

**PersonRepository**

```
public class PersonRepository {
    private static final String TAG = "RecipeRepository";
    private PersonDao personDao;
    private LiveData<List<Person>> people;
    private LiveData<List<PersonWithPets>> peopleWithPets;
    private LiveData<List<Pet>> pets;

    public PersonRepository (Application application) {
        PersonDatabase db = PersonDatabase.getInstance(application);
        personDao = db.personDao();
        people = personDao.getAllPeople();
        peopleWithPets = personDao.getAllPeopleWithPets();
        pets = personDao.getAllPets();
    }

    // Get all people with pets
    public LiveData<List<PersonWithPets>> getAllPeopleWithPets() {
        return peopleWithPets;
    }

    // Delete
    public void delete(Person person) {
        new DeletePersonAsyncTask(personDao).execute(person);
    }

    // Delete All People
    private static class DeleteAllPeopleAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private PersonDao personDao;
        private DeleteAllPeopleAsyncTask(PersonDao personDao) {
            this.personDao = personDao;
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            personDao.deleteAllPeople();
            //personDao.deleteAllPets();
            return null;
        }
    }
 }
```

**Database**

```
@Database(entities = {Person.class, Pet.class}, version = 5, exportSchema = false)
public abstract class PersonDatabase extends RoomDatabase {

    private static final String TAG = "PersonDatabase";
    private static PersonDatabase instance;
    public abstract PersonDao personDao();

    public static synchronized PersonDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if(instance == null){
            instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                    PersonDatabase.class, "person_database")
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .addCallback(roomCallback)
                    .build();
        }
        return instance;
    }

    private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback(){
        @Override
        public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
            super.onCreate(db);
            new PopulateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute();
        }
    };

    private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        private PersonDao personDao;
        private PopulateDbAsyncTask(PersonDatabase db){
            personDao = db.personDao();
        }
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Person adam = new Person();
            adam.setName("Adam");
            Pet dog = new Pet();
            dog.setName("Dog");
            adam.setPet(dog);
            Long personId = personDao.insertPerson(adam);
            for (Pet pet : adam.getPets()) {
                pet.setPersonId(personId.intValue());
                personDao.insertPet(pet);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**DAO**

```
@Dao
public interface PersonDao {
    @Transaction
    @Insert
    Long insertPerson(Person person);

    @Transaction
    @Insert
    void insertPet(Pet pet);

    @Transaction
    @Update
    int updatePerson(Person person);

    @Transaction
    @Delete
    void deletePerson(Person person);

    @Transaction
    @Query("DELETE FROM person")
    void deleteAllPeople();

    @Transaction
    @Query("DELETE FROM pet")
    void deleteAllPets();

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM person")
    LiveData<List<Person>> getAllPeople();

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM person")
    LiveData<List<PersonWithPets>> getAllPeopleWithPets();

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM pet")
    LiveData<List<Pet>> getAllPets();
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
viewModel.getAllPeopleWithPets().observe(this, new Observer<List<PersonWithPets>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(@Nullable List<PersonWithPets> peopleWithPets) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: --------------------------------");
                Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: ALL PEOPLE WITH PETS");
                for (PersonWithPets personWithPets : peopleWithPets) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: Name: " + personWithPets.getPerson().getName() + " ID: " + personWithPets.getPerson().getId());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: Pets: " + + personWithPets.getPets().size());
                    if (personWithPets.getPets().size() > 0) {
                        for (Pet pet : personWithPets.getPets()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: Name: " + pet.getName() + " ID: " + pet.getId() + " PersonID: " + pet.getPersonId());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: No pets.");
                    }
                }
                Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: --------------------------------");
                setTitle("People: " + peopleWithPets.size() + " Pets: " + viewModel.getAllPets().getValue().size());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove ForeignKey annotation from the field declaration to the top of the entity:

```
@Entity(tableName = "pet", foreignKeys = @ForeignKey
    (entity = Person.class,
            parentColumns = "id",
            childColumns = "personId",
            onDelete = CASCADE,
            onUpdate = CASCADE))
public class Pet {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Integer id;
.......................
```

It seems that @ForeignKey put above the field has no effect on creating foreign keys at all. You can see it both in the autogenerated Database Java class and checking the structure of table with any SQLite browser.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much for the example code and the clear explanation. Also, the tip with the SQLite browser is great, since I was wondering if there was a way to directly see my data. 
I am still getting this warning but i sure I will be able to fix it.
**warning: personId column references a foreign key but it is not part of an index. This may trigger full table scans whenever parent table is modified so you are highly advised to create an index that covers this column.**

Comment: For anyone interested: the fix for the warning was adding an index for personId in the entity definition:

```@Entity(tableName = "pet", 
        indices = {@Index(value = {"personId"})}, 
        foreignKeys = @ForeignKey(
                entity = Person.class,
                parentColumns = "id",
                childColumns = "personId",
                onDelete = CASCADE,
                onUpdate = CASCADE))
public class Pet {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private Integer id;

...```